# Angular / RxJS: How to generate a sequence of delayed values?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have array of messages.
Every `N` seconds I need to emit a message from Observable.

I tried the next code. First message was emitted with the delay and I got it in subscriber but generating of other messages in sequence was stopped.
If I remove `.delay()` method call I get the needed sequence, the subscriber reacts for each message, but without a time period between messages. How can I fix it?

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { fromArray } from 'rxjs/observable/fromArray';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessageService {

  constructor() { }

  getIncomingMessagesStream(): Observable<string> {
    const messageTimeout = 2000;

    const messages = ['Hi there!', 'How are you?', 'That is awesome :)'];

    return fromArray(messages)
      .delay(messageTimeout);
  }
}
```

Example of subscriber:

```
messageService.getIncomingMessagesStream()
    .subscribe(message => console.log('New incoming message ', message) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the chain emit the next item only after the previous item was delayed:

```
import { from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

return from(messages).pipe(
  concatMap(item => of(item).pipe(delay(messageTimeout))),
);
```

Btw, you're combining RxJS <5.5 and RxJS >= 5.5 styles (pipeable and prototype styles of operators). Better stick only with RxJS 5.5 and avoid `import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatMap';`. See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Jul 2019: Updated for RxJS 6.

See live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs5-hibr4m?file=index.ts

Comment: This is strange but I have the same result, subscriber works only for first message.

Comment: @AlexChaliy Well, the problem must be somewhere else because this works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs5-hibr4m?file=index.ts

Comment: I noticed the sequence works for the first message then it stops if I use expect() method inside a subscriber in test. [code example](http://prntscr.com/jqug86)

Comment: It stops how? Are you sure it's not because of the `delay()`. If you want to test chains that work with real time you should be using `TestScheduler`: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/marble-testing.md